# How to count the number of arithmetic operations in the following expression?

Tags: performance

exp(-(intA-FloatB)^2/(2*(FloatC^2)))
Note that the exponential is not complex!

Comment: What does this have to do with dates?

Comment: Do you need to count all the arithmetic operations involved in converting integer to float for `intA-FloatB`, and all the operations needed to implement `exp()`? Those are both implementation-dependent.

Comment: NO just for finding the exponential of these numbers if they are floating point and one of them is integer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the whitespace.

For simple arithmetic operators, count the number of `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and `^` characters. However, if one of these characters is followed by `+` or `-` and a digit, you should count this as just one operation -- the second is just the sign of a literal number. Also, if the expression begins with `+` or `-` followed by a digit, don't count it for the same reason.

For function calls, count `(` preceded by a letter or number.

Add these together and you get the total number of operations.